# js not getting border

Tags: javascript, dom

I am a newbie. I would like to change the color of my page to white but when changed, I want my .symbol class border to change to black but one of my symbols is not working although I don't see any problem. What could be the problem?

Here is my code below:

https://codepen.io/mizginyildirak/pen/zYmoYme

```js
function handleStyleColorChange() {
  if (event.target.matches('.white-btn')) {
    document.body.style.color = "#141516"
    document.querySelector(".symbol").style.borderColor = "#141516";

  } else {
    document.body.style.color = "#ced4e2"
    document.querySelector(".symbol").style.borderColor = "#ced4e2";
  }
}
```

I tried to add document.querySelector(".symbol").style.borderColor = "#ced4e2";

but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

That's happening because you have multiple elements have the same class so we need to loop through it and change the style one by one, you can try to do this:

```
function changeStyle(color) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".symbol").forEach((item) => {
         item.style.borderColor = color;
     });
}

function handleStyleColorChange() {
   if (event.target.matches('.white-btn')) {
      document.body.style.color = "#141516"
      changeStyle("#141516");
    } else {
      document.body.style.color = "#ced4e2"
      changeStyle("#ced4e2");
    }
}
```